# Building electron app breaks my angular 2 app

Tags: angular, electron

So after building my electron angular 2 app when I run it, my angular 2 app does not work anymore. No errors come up, but the app doesn't know how to route anymore so it just gets stuck at loading according to my index.html . Does it have something to with how asar is packing up my app? What can I do to make it run again?
File structure:

./package.json

----->./electron/main.js

```
 src/---> index.html
          app/app.routing.ts
          app/app.component.ts
          app/app.module.ts
          app/home/home.component.ts
          app/...All The other components......
```

index.html:

```
  <!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>New</title>
  <script>
   document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

   <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./public/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');</script>
   <script src="./public/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
     <app-root>
        Loading...
     </app-root>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
href="' + document.location + '"
```

replace with

```
href="./"
```

[here](https://github.com/Longfld/AngularRouter4Electron/blob/master/index.html) is how I do it